# Password_verify não retorna o correto

Tags: php

Estou tentando utilizar o comando `password_verify` porém ele não está me retornando o correto por exemplo:

```php
$senha = "151201";

$hash = "dc123878c3ceb4b521c7531ecaa93b53";

if(password_verify($senha, $hash)){
    $teste = "Senha correta";
    echo $teste;
} else {
    $teste = "Senha incorreta";
    echo $teste;
}
```

A variável `$hash`foi atribuída a String: `dc123878c3ceb4b521c7531ecaa93b53` que foi gerada no site: http://www.md5online.org/md5-encrypt.html apesar da string `151201` ser `dc123878c3ceb4b521c7531ecaa93b53` o comando continua me retornando `FALSE`

Comment: password_verify só funciona com password_hash http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.password-hash.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `password_hash` suporta *BCrypt* e *Argon2i* (no PHP 7.2). O MD5 nunca foi designado para senhas. Além disso desde 1994 ele já poderia ser considerado quebrado, hoje em dia ele não é recomendado para nada, mas essa não é a questão aqui.

---

Para que você use o `password_verify` é preferível que utilize uma senha compatível com o BCrypt (ou com o Argon2i no caso do PHP 7.2), você pode usar:

- Para BCrypt:

  ```
  password_hash($senha, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
  ```
- Para Argon2i:

  ```
  password_hash($senha, PASSWORD_ARGON2I);
  ```

> **/!\ Cuidado:**

O `password_hash` não remove os nulos e vai parar neles, portanto isso é quebrado:

```
// Não utilize o código abaixo em produção, existem erros intencionais:

$_POST['senha'] = "a\x00bc";
// Nota: Existe um nulo após o `a`, isso pode ser enviado usando `%00` pelo usuário!

$hash =  password_hash($_POST['senha'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

if(strlen($_POST['senha']) >= 3 && strlen($_POST['senha']) < 70){
    if( password_verify('a', $hash)){
        echo 'Igual';
    }
}
```

[Teste isto.](http://ideone.com/GA0lza)

Resultado: `Igual`, sim o `a` é igual ao `a\x00bc`. >:D

---

Se não quiser usar o BCrypt/Agon2i nem tudo está perdido, você pode usar o `PBKDF2`, por exemplo:

```
$senha = '12345678';
$salt = random_bytes(16);
$iteracoes = 150000;

$hash = hash_pbkdf2('sha3-512', $senha, $salt, $iteracoes);
```

Para verificar basta fazer `hash_equals($senha, $hash)`. Nunca faça `$senha === $hash` e muito menos faça `$senha == $hash`, obviamente. Ele não é considerado melhor que o BCrypt e nem muito menos melhor que o Argon2i, alguns dizem que é o "pior dos métodos recomendados", sendo usado "quando não tem nada melhor".

Answer (score 3):

O *hash* utilizado pela função [`password_verify`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.password-verify.php) não é apenas o MD5 da senha. Na verdade, a função é compatível com a função `crypt`, ou seja, o *hash* a ser utilizado deve ser este:

```
define("SALT", uniqid()); // Exemplo!

$senha = "151201";

$hash = crypt($senha, SALT);

if (password_verify($senha, $hash)) {
    $teste = "Senha correta";
    echo $teste;
} else {
    $teste = "Senha incorreta";
    echo $teste;
}
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/X6BXVj).

Ou você pode utilizar a função [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.password-hash.php) para gerar o *hash*:

```
$senha = "151201";

$hash = password_hash($senha, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

if (password_verify($senha, $hash)) {
    $teste = "Senha correta";
    echo $teste;
} else {
    $teste = "Senha incorreta";
    echo $teste;
}
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/vhOfM6).

Comment: Eu acho que usando `crypt` o resultado é um DES e não um BCrypt. Tanto que nem está ajustando a dificuldade, e não resultada em `$2$` que é o prefixo do BCrypt.